# Failed to download instructions to build and run your app, contact us if this error persists

Tags: trigger.io

Recently (as of around Nov 1), whenever I update a TriggerIO module to the most recent version (as prompted by a "your modules are out of date" message on the TriggerIO Toolkit), it tries to "download instructions to build the app" but then always fails after about 5 seconds with this message:

"Failed to download instructions to build and run your app, contact us if this error persists."

Thus preventing me from running the app or doing anything..

This did not used to be a problem..

UPDATE: it just started working again - I clicked the "Shutdown Toolkit" button on Trigger Toolkit and then it seemed to work? Closing the browser window earlier didn't seem to fix it but maybe clicking that button does? Or it was just coincidence..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The "Shutdown Toolkit" button on the top right of the header (NOT just closing the browser) and then restarting the toolkit seems to be a fix.